# Theory what is meant by validating security concerns for these user groups

Tags: theory

First of all this is probably being asked in the wrong section, if that is the case then i am sorry, i was not sure where to post this to.

I am doing revision using past exams and there is a question that i am not sure how to answer, there is  nothing in the course material which any reference to the contents of this question.

the question states:

```
Explain your understanding of the specific IT security concerns of each of
these three classes of stakeholder within the university. Describe how, in
each case, you would seek to validate this understanding.
(i) Corporate managers; 
(ii) IT service providers; 
(iii) Undergraduate service users.
```

Now, so far i have identified some concerns:

```
(i) Internal leaks
(ii) malicious attacks, phising, etc
(iii) Data protection issues
```

But i have no idea what validate these mean. Could anybody point me in the right direction in terms of where to research the answer, or provide an insight into what the question is asking.

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"validate this understanding" is gross corporate-speak. What the question is asking is "what do each of these users care about?"

You're on the right track with separating out the concerns of each party. I would answer the question by explaining how the current security infrastructure does or does not address the specific needs of each party.